# embed youtube video doesn't play automatically on device mode of google chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ionic-framework, youtube

I'm trying to add embed youtube video in my Ionic project, just using iframe.
Once I added, it works on the normal web browser(Google Chrome).

However, if I changed view mode to device mode(`F12` & `Ctrl+Shift+M`), and refresh browser, the embed video stopped auto-playing. Is there anyone have experience before fixed like this problem?

Here is the similar case with mine: http://jsfiddle.net/eFLqJ/1005/

Answer (score 0):

This module will be helpful for your problem: https://github.com/orizens/ng2-youtube-player